# Procedure not executing all lines of code

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently having an issue with a VBA script. It jumps over some lines of code without any error message. The strange about it is, this behavior does not happen for all users that work with the VBA script.

The VBA script is part of an Excel workbook and is designed, to call a second procedure during the runtime. This second procedure should build a form and do some further actions (formatting, etc.). The VBA script enters the second procedure but does not execute one line out of it. Instead it just continues with the code from the main procedure.

```
    Sub Main()
    Dim oClient as Object
    ...
    'Call procedure to create form
    Call CreateForm(oClient)
    ...
    End Sub


    Sub CreateForm(ByRef oClient As Object)
    Dim oForm As Object

    Set oForm = oClient.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(3)
    With oForm
        .Properties("Caption") = "Partner Export"
        .Properties("Name") = "frmPartner"
        .Properties("Width") = 300
        .Properties("Height") = 240
    End With
    ...
    End Sub
```

The code is reduced to the minimum to show the procedures. The real VBA code is way bigger and more complex- that is the reason why I split it into two procedures. 
The object `oClient` is created in the main procedure and passed to the `CreateForm` procedure. After calling `CreateForm`, the VBA script just skips all lines of the sub without notification.

What could be the reason for this behavior? Especially with the background, that this does not appear for each user of it.

Comment: **oClient** is never **Set**

Comment: oClient is set in the main procedure. It is just not displayed in the code above.

Comment: I'd guess that "Trust programmatic access to VBA object model" needs to be turned on for those users, although they should be getting errors unless you've suppressed them.

Comment: ok, the issue is indeed due to the macro security setting as mentioned above. After activating this, the macro works like for the other users as well.

Answer (score 0):

You confirmed my suspicions in the comments, and the solution is to "Trust programmatic access to VBA project object model" in the Macro Security settings. This allows VBA to refer to `VBProject` objects.